# Trouble configuring dojo from CDN to local

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a simple hello app that I was playing with.  This works when I use the CDN however when I switch to a local copy it does not.

This is my dojo script.

```
$(function () {    
    require([
        'dojo/dom',
        'dojo/fx',
        'dojo/domReady!'
    ], function (dom, fx) {
        var greeting = dom.byId('greeting');
        greeting.innerHTML += ' from Dojo!';

        fx.slideTo({
            node: greeting,
            top: 100,
            left: 200
        }).play();
    });
});
```

And this is my configuration.

```
<script>
    dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        baseUrl: '.',
        packages: [
            'dojo',
            'digit',
            'dojox',
            'demo'
        ]
    };
</script>

@*<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>*@
<script src="~/Scripts/dojo.js"></script>
```

I know that it's finding dojo (I tested with a simpler example)  However it appears that it's not finding the dojo-fx.

I installed the following from Nuget:

```
- dijit Source
- dojo Source
- dojo
```

Comment: Isn't your dojo path referencing minified dojo? Try referencing dojo.js from `dojo Source` package (and if it success you can get rid of NuGet's `dojo` package described as minified version)

Answer (score 1):

Your "require" declaration should be in this manner:

```
require(["dojo/_base/fx", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"]
```